# Bash find string postion in list of strings

Tags: bash, shell

Whats the best way to achieve the following?

I want my script to find out which postion the host its running on is in a list of hosts.

```
thisHost=$(hostname)

machineList="pc02 server03 host01 server05"
```

So if `thisHost=host01` I would get back postion 3.

The machine list would never be contain more than 10 items.

I could do a comparison  match in a for loop but would like to know if there is a better way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`Bash`** solution:

```
thisHost="host01"
machineList="pc02 server03 host01 server05"
machineListArr=($machineList)

for i in "${!machineListArr[@]}"; do 
    [ "$thisHost" = "${machineListArr[$i]}" ] && echo "position: $((i+1))"
done
```

The output:

```
position: 3
```

Answer (score 4):

If you need to check many hosts, you can prepare a better structure for faster lookup: an associative array:

```
#! /bin/bash
machineList='pc02 server03 host01 server05'
declare -A machine_number
i=1
for machine in $machineList ; do
    machine_number[$machine]=$((i++))
done

thisHost=host01
echo ${machine_number[$thisHost]}
```

You can also use external tools:

```
read n _rest < <(echo "$machineList"
                 | tr ' ' '\n'
                 | nl
                 | grep -Fw "$thisHost")
echo $n
```

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question to say the list would only be a 10 or so machines

Answer (score 1):

**`Awk`** *one-line* solution:

```
thisHost="host01"
machineList="pc02 server03 host01 server05"

awk -v RS=" " -v h="$thisHost" '$0==h{ print NR }' <<<"$machineList"
```

The output:

```
3
```

Answer (score 1):

(1) An inexpensive one-liner:

```
    host='host01'
    machineList="pc02 server03 host01 server05"

    wc -w <<< ${machineList/%${host}*/dummy}
```

Substitute the rest of the list beginning with `$host` with `dummy` and count the words with `wc`.

(2) Pure Bash:

```
    host='host01'
    machineList="pc02 server03 host01 server05"

    shortList=( ${machineList/%${host}*/dummy} )
    echo  ${#shortList[@]}
```

Shorten the list as shown above and return the number of elements of the array `shortList`.

The output is 3 in both solutions.